# How to wrap a column in a CAST operation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an MSSQL database with tables which I cannot change and only ever interact with it as read only (SELECT statements). I am using sqlalchemy. What I need to do is to automatically wrap specific columns in CAST() SQL operations for every query. I want to do this at a low level so my code never needs to think about the problem. The reason I am doing this is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785670/can-i-use-pyodbc-freetds-and-sqlalchemy-with-decimal-data-in-mssql).

My table is something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class myTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'mytable'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('table_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    problem_field = Column(DECIMAL(12, 4), nullable=True)
```

I have been trying to use a TypeDecorator like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Sequence, types
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast

Base = declarative_base()

class CastToFloatType(types.TypeDecorator):
    '''Converts stored Decimal values to Floats via CAST operation
    '''
    impl = types.Numeric
    def column_expression(self, col):
        return cast(col, Float)

class myTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'mytable'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('table_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    wrapped_field = Column(CastToFloatType, nullable=True)
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need to make sure you're on at least version 0.8 of SQLAlchemy, where the `column_expression()` feature was added.   A simple test of your code works on this end:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Sequence, types, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast

Base = declarative_base()

class CastToFloatType(types.TypeDecorator):
    '''Converts stored Decimal values to Floats via CAST operation
    '''
    impl = types.Numeric
    def column_expression(self, col):
        return cast(col, Float)

class myTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'mytable'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('table_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    wrapped_field = Column(CastToFloatType, nullable=True)

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
s = Session()
print s.query(myTable)
```

output:

```
SELECT mytable.id AS mytable_id, CAST(mytable.wrapped_field AS FLOAT) AS mytable_wrapped_field 
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thanks @zzzeek I was running a 0.7. I'm now back on track. This has been a long-running problem for me and I might be on the way to a wider solution. Thanks for sqlalchemy, it makes my life easier.